# PHP in Template Forbidden - Can't even save

Tags: templates, php

On EE 2.11.7, I've enabled PHP on a template and set it to output and even a simple echo of some text between PHP opening and closing tags results in a Forbidden error page when I try to save the template.

Site is on Nexcess and mod_security doesn't seem to be on when looking at phpInfo, so not sure what is going on. Any insights on what may be causing this and how to fix it?